# How to create a sticky notification in plain HTML CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello everyone I need to create 3 different types of dialog boxes for school but the way it's worded I cannot find information online of how to do it. I need to create a sticky popup that is **unintrusive**! to the screen and untimed. Closed by clicking the x in the popup. I have a growl notification already that is timed. Now I don't even know what to look for as the internet has me going in circles the image I attached [best explanation of nitication I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcjxT.jpg)

is the closest description of what I need to create. If anyone can point me in the right direction I would be very grateful.

I tried searching on the internet. I have created a flash notification and can figure out an alert but "sticky" popup dialog box I cannot find. To be able to scroll and have an unintrusive, untimed, notification or dialog box as my school calls them this is the assignment[school assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwKD9.jpg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This notification will be at the bottom even if you will scroll.

```js
function addNotification(){
//create notification
const NotiElement = document.createElement("div");
NotiElement.id = "stickyNotification";
NotiElement.style.display = "block";
NotiElement.style.position = "absolute";
NotiElement.style.width = "290px";
NotiElement.style.height = "90px";
NotiElement.style.padding = "10px";
NotiElement.style.borderRadius = "5px";
NotiElement.style.border = "1px solid black";
NotiElement.style.backgroundColor = "red";
NotiElement.style.right = "10px";
NotiElement.style.bottom = "10px";
NotiElement.innerHTML = " <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</span><div id='closeBtn'>X</div>";
document.body.appendChild(NotiElement);
//keep it always at the bottom corner of the window
document.addEventListener("scroll", (event) => {
    let btmPos = -window.scrollY + 10;
    NotiElement.style.bottom = btmPos + "px";
  });
  //add close event to remove child
document.getElementById("closeBtn").addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    document.body.removeChild(NotiElement);
  });
}
//call function
addNotification();
```

```css
#stickyNotification #closeBtn{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 5px;
}
#stickyNotification #closeBtn:hover{
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
body{
height: 200vh;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it with good animations, is to create an element with a `position: fixed` in CSS.

then push the element outside of the screen by a 100% of it's width with `transform: translateX()`.

then add a class to it that returns the element to its original position with the same CSS function.

you can add or remove the class using JavaScript through an `onclick` attribute on the HTML element or adding a click listener on the element

```js
const closeElement = document.getElementById('notification');

const toggleNotification = () => {
  closeElement.classList[closeElement.classList.contains('open') ? 'remove' : 'add']('open');
}

const closeNotification = () => {
  closeElement.classList.remove('open')
}

const openNotification = () => {
  closeElement.classList.add('open')
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.growl {
  position: fixed;
  right: 1rem;
  bottom: 1rem;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  min-width: 300px;
  min-height: 50px;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  transform: translateX(calc(100% + 1rem));
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.open {
  transform: translateX(0px);
}

.growl .close-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="openNotification()">Open</button>
  <button onclick="toggleNotification()">toggle</button>
  <div id="notification" class="growl">
    <p>This is a small notification</p>
    <span id="close-btn" onclick="closeNotification()" class="close-btn">X</span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.alert("Hello World") to open a pop up you are trying to define.

Comment: Thank you. Thisis part of my assignment but the notification I am trying to create is unintrusive. thank you for answering so quickly

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>
Here is your HTML Content
</p>

<div id="pop_up">
<div id="close_pop_up">X</div>
    Here is your text
</div>

<style>
#pop_up{
   background: gray;
   position: absolute;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   right: 20px;
   bottom: 20px;
}
</style>
<script>
 const closePopUp = document.getElementById("close_pop_up");
 closePopUp.addEventListener("click", () =>{
     document.getElementById("pop_up").style.display = "none";
 });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

In your HTML code you can add a element that have an absolute position and will be your pop-up.

```
<div id="pop_up">
    Here is your text
</div>

#pop_up{
   position: absolute;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   right: 20px;
   bottom: 20px;
}
```

This is the first step if you want a sticky notification on your website.You can change the values of the css above depending on your needs.
Now if you want to close it you need to 1. add you x to you element:

```
<div id="pop_up">
  <div id="close_pop_up">X</div>
  Here is your text
</div>
```

2. Add a listener with javascript to hide the notification when you cilck on the X.

   ```
    const closePopUp = document.getElementById("close_pop_up");
    closePopUp.addEventListener("click", () =>{
        document.getElementById("pop_up").style.display = "none";
    });
   ```

You can add this script in a `<script></script>` just before the end on the enclosure tag body of your html.

Comment: Thank You very much. The last few post have worked perfectly. Since I can't upvote I left a comment here.